"Asseh Lecha Rav" and location
When choosing a personal rabbi, should it be according to the location (same neighborhood/city/country) according to the Mara De'Atra principle?

1 "Asseh Lecha Rav" is NOT a Halachic principle, there's no Halachic obligation to "have a guiding rabbi". Many Orthodox and Ultra-Orthodox Jews do not associate with any rabbi in particular. 2 IIRC, Mara De'Atra applies where there's only one rabbi/court in town/village. Once there is more than one, anyone's free to follow either.

Before phones, what other choice was there?

The Rambam doesn't mention location, but he offers an original, insightful interpretation of the Mishna:

[Make for yourself a teacher] means [make him play that role] even if he is not fit to be your mentor.  Place him upon you as a mentor, so that you can discuss and argue with him.  As a result of this, wisdom will come into your hand.
If a man studies on his own, it is good; but if he studies with someone else, the teaching will be better established in his hand and it will be clearer -- even if his partner is like him or even below him in wisdom. (On Avot 1:6)


Okay but for halachic matters would the choice depend of the location as halakha take into account location for psakim ?

The Rambam seems to be saying: Pick anybody. That being the case, the closest candidate will do. For a halachic question, CYLOR.

So it is no related to Mara Detra, or on the feeling with this rabbi?

Aseh lekha Rav refers to who you study with, as per Rambam. Your Mara de-Atra refers to who you go to for halachic decisions. They don't have to be the same person.
